# Как раздедить строку на массив с разными разделителями Java

Tags: java, массивы, строки, split

Есть строка:

```
String str = "c:/tmp/java.txt.part1";
```

Как правильно ее разбить на массив?

```
array[0] = "java";
array[1] = "txt";
array[2] = "part1";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `split` в качестве первого аргумента принимает регулярное выражение, соотвестственно там можно перечислить несколько разделителей, разделенных в свою очередь символом `|`:

```
src = "c:/tmp/java.txt.part1";
for (String s: src.split("/|\\.")) {
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

Выведет

```
с:
tmp
java
txt
part1
```

Если Вам нужно тоько имя файла, разделенное по точкам (путь не нужен), то:

```
String src = "c:/tmp/java.txt.part1";
String[] srclist = src.split("/");
String[] parts_of_name = srclist[srclist.length - 1].split("\\.");
```

Comment: Спасибо! то что надо.